re: Google Cloud Run Job - what is property "observedGeneration"?
If you run gcloud run jobs describe my_job --format json, the last property is called observedGeneration, and seems to get bumped when you make a change to the job.
I can infer the purpose from this, but... why can't I find any documentation about it?  It'd be nice to be sure about the meaning - that is, under what conditions it's incremented, and what guarantees that offers.
UPDATE:  I should also point out the metadata.generation property which matches the value of observedGeneration.  I don't know the difference between those two.

Google documents all of its services.
You can access this documentation through e.g. APIs Explorer
For Cloud Run
For gcloud run jobs describe --log-http == projects.locations.jobs.get

Output only. A number that monotonically increases every time the user modifies the desired state.

